# Can malicious files be traced and removed from my phone

Tags: malware, file-upload, user-tracking, remote-code-execution

I had a files analysis done on my phone using Falcon Sandbox. An alarming amount of malicious files,marked as clean, were found,identified,and shown each capable abilities. Literally THE ONLY thing of numerous apps/companies/etc I used that could find much less pin point what these files are being used for. Now having knowledge of their presence is there a way to trace where from and how each was downloaded and can they be removed?